# In Emacs, How to export Links to a clickable link, when htmlize emacs buffer?

Tags: html, emacs, lisp, elisp, org-mode

**BACKGROUND**

1. I using great [htmlize.el](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize) to export my org-mode buffer contents with font [hi-lock.](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Highlight-Interactively.html)
2. Emacs org-mode has a [Link format.](http://orgmode.org/manual/Link-format.html)

**PROBLEM**

For Example, here is a org-mode file with contents:

```
[[http://hunmr.blogspot.com][blog]]
```

When I Using [Htmlize.el](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize) to htmlize buffer to HTML contents, The link was missing.
produces HTML like:

```
<span style="hyperlinkFOOBAR">blog</span>
```

**EXPECTED**

I expected it produces clickable link like:

```
<a style="hyperlinkFOOBAR" href="http://hunmr.blogspot.com">blog</a>
```

**QUESTION**

**EDIT1** The org-export-as-html can export link, but can not create CSS for the Hi-locks.

- Do you know other ways to to export org-mode links to HTML?
- To read the real link in org-mode buffer using elisp, how to do that? read text
  property?

THANKS IN ADVANCE, YOUR HELP WILL BE HIGHLY APPRECIATED.

Comment: **CLUE1**
I find the code, how org-mode show the link in OVERVIEW. 
`(defun org-columns-compact-links (s)
  "Replace [[link][desc]] with [desc] or [link]."
  (while (string-match org-bracket-link-regexp s)
    (setq s (replace-match
      (concat "[" (match-string (if (match-end 3) 3 1) s) "]")
      t t s)))
  s)`


**TO BE CONTINUE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Andreas 's hints, I add following code to htmlize.el. Currently the org-link can be htmlized to clickable link.

The code was shared on github:

https://github.com/whunmr/dotemacs/blob/master/site-lisp/htmlize.el

and

http://hunmr.blogspot.com/2012/08/enhance-htmlizeel-now-can-export-org.html

**FOLLOWING IS THE MAIN CODE:**

```
(defun expand-org-link (&optional buffer)
  "Change [[url][shortname]] to [[url] [shortname]] by adding a space between url and shortname"
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\\[\\[\\([^][]+\\)\\]\\(\\[\\([^][]+\\)\\]\\)?\\]"
                nil t)
    (let ((url (match-string 1))
      (link-text (match-string 3)))
      (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
      (insert "[[" url "] [" link-text "]]"))))

(defun shrink-org-link (&optional buffer)
  "Change [[url] [shortname]] to [[url][shortname]], remove the space between url and shortname"
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\\[\\[\\([^][]+\\)\\] \\(\\[\\([^][]+\\)\\]\\)?\\]"
                nil t)
    (let ((url (match-string 1))
      (link-text (match-string 3)))
      (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
      (insert "[[" url "][" link-text "]]"))))

(defun transform-org-link ()
  "transform htmlized <span> to <a>"
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\\[\\[<span \\([^>]+\\)>\\([^][]+\\)</span>\\] \\[\\([^][]+\\)\\]\\]"
                nil t)
    (let ((style (match-string 1))
          (url (match-string 2))
      (link-text (match-string 3)))
      (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
      (insert "<a " style " href=\"" url "\">" link-text "</a>"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

org-export-as-html should DTRT

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thanks for your help.  The main reason I use the htmlize.el is to Keep the Hi-lock patterns highlighted, after exporting. But org-export-as-html currently can not keep the highlight fonts.      So I think maybe we need add the link exporting function to the htmlize.el.

Comment: Great thanks, maybe I can find some important clues from code of org-export-as-html .